# add a share button in Firefox OS application

Tags: firefox, share, firefox-os

I am creating a firefox OS application, I want the user to be able to share a link through any application installed and eligible (facebook, twitter etc). I saw android has this kind of feature and firefox OS has it as well, as I saw it in one of it's built in applications. Went through Web API, didn't find a suitable match,

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the intended use of the [Web Activity API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Web_Activities) .  The idea is that applications register to handle activities like share.  The [Firefox OS Boiler Plate](https://github.com/robnyman/Firefox-OS-Boilerplate-App) app has several examples of using Web Activities. In that example a user could share a url using code like:

> ```
> var share = document.querySelector("#share");
> if (share) {
>     share.onclick = function () {
>         new MozActivity({
>             name: "share",
>             data: {
>                 number: 1,
>                 url: "http://robertnyman.com"
>             }
>         });
>     };
> }
> ```

Any app that handles the share activity will be shown allowing the user to pick the proper app to handle the share.

Comment: I am refering to the latest version of the boilerplate app, when I share the URL, I dont see Facebook app actually getting the URL. Here is a snapshot of what I am getting: http://i.imgur.com/aBOdbZC.png I didnt change the boilerplate code at all. Also, there is no error in the console. Any idea how to fix this?